# Why does my Windows clock keep going out of time?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, date-time

My clock doesn't stay synced. I can sync via settings and it works for a bit but then it goes out again after a while.

Auto-sync with time server is selected.

I have tried restarting the Windows Time service and it doesn't help the problem.

I am not dual booting.

Comment: [Edit] your question to indicate if you are dual booting into Linux.  Any and all information about your question should be added to your question body instead of a comment.

Comment: https://smallbusiness.chron.com/day-time-desktop-computer-keep-changing-68787.html but in your case you should *select* the check box for "Synchronize with an Internet Time Server"

Comment: It is selected, that's why I'm confused

Comment: Then de-select it, configure the time correctly, and reboot. Does your computer think it is in the wrong time zone? Is your CMOS Battery ok? https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-reasons-windows-computer-loses-time-date/

Comment: @SuperHandz98 - It goes without saying, you should be editing your question, instead of replying to our comments

Comment: I've literally edited everything I've said in the comments into the post. Look at the edits.

Comment: @SuperHanz98 For internet time synchronizaton, I've always found it's better or use [NIST's timeserver](https://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi) [`time.nist.gov`], or the equivalent of the country residing in, over the default time servers Windows is configured with.

Comment: How exactly does it go out of sync? Does it drift slowly? Or does it jump in larger intervals like maybe hours?

Comment: CMOS is seeming like the best answer so far, it is an old PC

Comment: Then it is most likely the CMOS battery. This is good news, because they are cheap and usually easy to replace.